# How to convert only elements and attributes in a string xpath query in java to upper case

Tags: java, xpath

I am a beginner to `xpath` and wanted to convert only the attributes and element name present in a string query into upper case.
This query will be passed to `Xpath`.evaluate function to get the node specified by this string.

I have a java function, where from a document, i get an `XPath`.

```
String path= document.getXPath();
```

And from this i find the node referred by this `xpath`,using `javax.xml.xpath.XPath.evaluate(path,node,XPathConstants.NODESET);`
My aim is to convert the string "path" returned, to upper case for elements and attributes only.

For e.g the path can be
`/abc/*[@xyz='123'/wer[1][ancestor-or-self::uio]`
where abc , wer and uio are element name and xyz is attribute name.

I need to convert only these to upper case, because in the document where xpath will search , these are in the upper case.
Since xpath is case sensitive, i dont want the xpath keywords/functions like "ancestor-or-self", "not", "contains" etc to be converted to upper case.

After conversion the path should be-
`/ABC/*[@XYZ='123'/WER[1][ancestor-or-self::UIO]`

Can anybody please provide pointers to me, how this can be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex here:

```
public static String upperCaseNodes(String xpath) {
   String ret = xpath;   

   Pattern rP = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<=/|@|::)([a-z\\d-_]+)");
   Matcher mP = rP.matcher(before);

   while (mP.find()) {
      String match = mP.group(1);
      ret = ret.replaceAll(match, match.toUpperCase());
   }

   return ret;
}

System.out.println(upperCaseNodes("/abc/*[@xyz='123'/wer[1][ancestor-or-self::uio]"));
```

#### Output

```
/ABC/*[@XYZ='123'/WER[1][ancestor-or-self::UIO]
```

Comment: Thanks Alex,But the path returned can be anything and does not fall into any pattern... it could be   /abc/wer[not(@key = ' ' and (contains(./ref[1]/@key, 'val1') or contains(./ref[1]/@key, 'val2')))]

Comment: @user3153654 The regex is generic, it will find any node in any path. The sample code was just an example.

Comment: Thanks .. I will try and find a regex which will fit in all my cases.

Comment: There is no regex that will fit all cases, because XPath is not a language that can be parsed using regular expressions alone.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get into this mess? Why is the XPath expression in the wrong case?

Changing the document to lower-case might be easier than changing the XPath expression to uppercase.

A 100% correct solution requires full parsing of the XPath expression, which you could do by finding an open-source XPath parser and incorporating it into your application.

But you might be able to get a solution that is sufficiently near to correct by converting all "words" (sequences of letters and digits) that don't match words in some exception list, where the exception list would include axis names, operators such as "and" and "or", and names of system functions like "contains".